# QgsMapRenderer to export current extent using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to accomplish PyQGIS simple map rendering via the QGIS 2.0 Python console, but end up with only a blank image. I've followed instructions of this [link](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#simple-rendering). My objective is to export a simple image of the current extent of layers of interest to a png. Where can I be going wrong?

```
#identify crs
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3297, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set image's background color
color = QColor(255,255,255)
img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

render = QgsMapRenderer()

#set crs
render.setDestinationCrs(crs)

# set layer set
layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface.layers()
lst = []
for layer in layers:
    lst.append(layer.())

render.setLayerSet(lst)

# set to CURRENT extent**map of layer's full extent is successfully rendered when QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent() is used)
rect = QgsRectangle(render.extent())
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)

# set output size
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

# do the rendering
render.render(p)

p.end()

# save image
img.save("render.png","png")
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this is just a typo in your post, but if not, this could cause a blank image..

```
# set layer set
layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface.layers()
```

This should actually be qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers() 
(note that legendInterface must be the method call, done by adding braces() )

```
lst = []
for layer in layers:
    lst.append(layer.())
```

What you want to do, is to add each layers id by appending layer.id()

 Hope that helps!

Edit: 
Did you try to save a layer with scale-based visibility enabled? Cause the renderer scales the image to full-extend prior to saving - maybe your layer data is invisible at that zoom-level?!

Btw. this is the code that worked for me (or at least with the vector-, shape-, and raster layers I tested it with ;) )

PS. When using rect = QgsRectangle(renderer.extent()) instead of renderer.fullExtent() the image I get is blank, too.

```
    imageType = "png"
    pathToFile = "/Users/%u/Desktop/"

    # create image
    img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

    # set image's background color
    color = QColor(255,255,255)
    img.fill(color.rgb())

    # create painter
    p = QPainter()
    p.begin(img)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

    renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
    # set layer set
    lst = []


    layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        lst.append(layer.id())

    renderer.setLayerSet(lst)
    print "Set rendered"

    # set extent
    rect = QgsRectangle(renderer.fullExtent())
    rect.scale(1.1)
    renderer.setExtent(rect)

    # set output size
    renderer.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

    print "Prepared to render"

    # do the rendering
    renderer.render(p)

    print "rendered"
    p.end()
    print "painter ended"
    # save image
    img.save(pathToFile + self.activeLayer.name() + "." + imageType ,imageType)
```